# Difficult permutation and inclusion-exclusion principle problem.

Tags: permutations, inclusion-exclusion

An Engineering student is given 5 glasses, each containing a different type of beer. He is told the names of the beers but not which glasses they are in. After drinking each beer he names it. In how many ways can he get every answer wrong?

The answer to this problem is 44:

This question has me completely stumped. I know that you have to find all the possible ways he/she guesses the beer, which is just 5! = 120. But that's pretty much all I know, and after that, I have no idea what to do or how the inclusion-exclusion principle comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is difficult to count how many ways he get all guesses wrong, let us count the complement: how many ways he get at least one guess correct.

By PIE, it is $\sum_{i=1}^{5}{-(-1)^{i}\binom{5}{i}\times(5-i)!}=76$. Subtracting this from $120$ gives us $44$

Comment: I get the complement part, and I  understand why (5-i)! appears in the expression for the sigma summation, but I don't why 5Ci is in there. you are wanting to find all the possible ways in which the person gets 1 correct and then summing them up, why is the combination there?

Comment: @TomTurner because if we say $i$ guesses are correct, we need to choose which $i$ from $5$ guesses that is.

Comment: Ohhhh, I think I get it, so say we have 5 bottles, _ _ _ _ _, if we want all the ways in which the student guessed just 1 correctly, it could be any of the 5 bottles, C _ _ _ _, _ C_ _ _, _ _ C _ _, _ _ _ C _, _ _ _ _ C, which is just 5C1. And the same would apply for guessing exactly 2, 3, 4 correctly. Right?

Comment: @DomTurner spot on!

Comment: Hold on, I just realized, $\sum_{i=1}^5 \binom{5}{i} \times (5-i)! \neq 76$. I think what you have to do is use the inclusion-exclusion principle for 5 sets, where A1 is the set in which glass 1 is correctly named, A2 is the set in which glass 2 is correctly named, .... And then find the union of the five sets (|A1 U A2 U A3 U A4 U A5|) using the formula for the inclusion-exclusion which will give you 76. Then subtract 120 from 76. I'm 95% confident that should give you 44, but haven't verified by doing the working out yet. I think $\sum_{i=1}^5 \binom{5}{i} \times (5-i)!$ gives you 206.

Comment: @DomTurner forgot the $-(-1)^{i}$ lol

Comment: oh ok, so does that just make it so that the sign switches correctly for the inclusion-exclusion formula? So | A1 U A2 U A3 U A4 .... An | = (|A1| + |A2| + |A3| + |A4| + .... |An|) - (|A1 AND A2| + |A3 AND A 4| + ..........) + (|A1 AND A2 AND A3| + ..........) - .... + ...... -

Comment: @DomTurner yup, the purpose of the $(-1)^i$ term is to get the signs to alternate from $+$ to $-$.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a *[derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)*:  a permutation in which every object changes position (here actual beer name and guessed name).

The number of ways is known as the subfactorial of $n$ or the $n$-th derangement number or $n$-th de Montmort number.  It is denoted $!n$, where $!2 = 1$, $!3=2$ and in general:

$$!n = (n-1)(!(n-1) + !(n-2))$$

Indeed, $!5 = 44$, as you can check yourself.

Comment: Interesting, solution, notation and way of looking at the problem, but I haven't learned about derangements or subfactorials yet so I'm struggling to see how that reasoning makes sense.

Comment: @DomTurner:  Read the linked article.